# Appending JSON Data from PHP to script after JQuery Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to load my JSON Data into my script after an ajax call, but I can't seem to be getting it right.

I have a Javascript library that loads a set of music by having a set of JSON data. For example, this is how loading the script with a few songs would look like:

```
<script>
    Amplitude.init({
        "songs": [
            {
                "name": "Song Name 1",
                "artist": "Super Dj",
                "album": "2018 Super Hit",
                "url": "songs/1.mp3",
                "cover_art_url": "../album-art/2018superhit.png"
            },
            {
                "name": "Song Name 2",
                "artist": "Super Dj",
                "album": "2018 Super Hit",
                "url": "songs/2.mp3",
                "cover_art_url": "../album-art/2018superhit.png"
            }
        ]
    });
</script>
```

Now, I'm trying to fetch the songs list `data` from my database using an ajax call, to populate this list of songs dynamically. PHP-wise, it's all good and the data is fine. However, on the ajax call, the `Amplitude.init`  does not work when I add my JSON `data` to it. The code below will give you a better idea of what I mean:

```
$(".mu-container").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var albumId = $(this).attr("data-album");
    $("#musicContainer").fadeIn();
    $("#playerRibbon").fadeIn();
    $.ajax({
        url: "includes/app/load_music.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: "album_id="+albumId,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data)
        {
            Amplitude.init({
                "songs": [
                    data
                ]
            });
        },
        error: function(err)
        {
            alert(err);
        }
   });
});
```

Finally, here's my PHP code which returns the JSON data, that I want to load into `Amplitude.init` after the ajax call is made:

```
//Database connection done above
$data = array();
foreach($songs as $song){
    $data[] = array("name" => $song['title'], "artist" => $song['artist'], "album" => $song['album_title'], "url" => $song['url'], "cover_art_url" => $song['album_art']);
}

echo json_encode($data); //If I run the php as a standalone with a test ID, it works just fine
```

Comment: Try using JSON.parse(data) in your JQuery success callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Amplitude.init({
    "songs": data
});
```

Because `data` is already an array of objects.

Comment: I tried that but the Amplitude.init still doesn't load for some reason. Which gets me wondering, is it possible to actually load the Amplitude.init in the ajax just like that with no <script> tags?

Comment: What response do you get in developers console? Are there any errors in console too?

Comment: It's actually working now, I made a mistake in my php after all. The solution you posted works now. Thanks!